# Alfresco community 4.2.c pagination

Tags: pagination, alfresco, yui, alfresco-share

In our old project we're using Alfresco 4.2.c community version.
There's a task page there, were you can use predefined filters to manage data you want to see.
I was able to add some extra filters there, anyway another problem stands in my way.
There's a paginator there, probably from YUI, which works by two parameters, maxCount and skipCount.
Right now it's configured to show max 400 records on one page.
I'm trying to add an option to display all records at once. Is anyone familiar enough with that system to even tell if it's possible? YUI framework is very hard to manage.

It seems like on every page or filter change it redirects you to ahref='#', a then a method reads the filter id and gives some extra parameters to the request. I can't find a way to maybe bind another button to reload the page in the same manner and just add another line to the request, which would make the paginator show all the records at one page.

Comment: Be aware that even if you succeed on the gui part, alfresco webscripts are searching in an index, which by definition is not designed to return a full query set. You might have to change the query limit or create your own webscript which will be iterating in your full result set.

Comment: Trying to return everything is futile, IMHO. You'll either have to go to the DB, or change the Lucene limit to something rather large, or create your own code that will run in batches, all of which is not really recommended; paging is there for a reason. Is there a reason why you're looking to do this, maybe there's something else that can be done?